# Using grep -m to save X amount of lines into new zipped file

Tags: linux

I have a file that has this pattern (the following text is equivalente to 1 sequence):

```
@A00479:60:HL5HKDSXX:1:1101:1759:1000 1:N:0:CAGCGTTA
TGAGCCACAGACCCTGGATCCCTCCCTGAGGTCCCATGGGACGGGCAGGCTGGGCATACCTGCAGAGAAGATGTGGCCAGCCACGGCCAGGAACGCATCGGTCACCACAGGCTCAGACTGCAGGGAGATGTGCAGCTGACGCGCCACGTTG
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I'd like to use grep to "pick" the first 100 sequences that have the pattern "@" and save that to a new zipped file

I was trying something like this

```
gzip | grep -m 10 @ test_seq_R1.fasta | cat test_seq_R1.fasta > test_seq_R1_zipped
```

But it is basically returning the same content from the original file test_seq_R1.fasta.

How can I choose the first 100 sequences that initiate with the @ pattern and zip it to a new file using `grep` and `gzip`?

Thank you

Comment: The -m flag isn't limiting you to 10 in this instance?

Comment: Ye that was a typo, should be 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggesting an `awk` script:

```
 awk 'count < 101 && /^@/ {++count; print}' input.txt
```